# Deleting some observations in near table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity, delete

I created some near tables, with a max near distance of 8000m. It is extremely timely exporting these files to csv right now.

Is there a quick way in ArcGIS to delete observations that have a distance of more than 250m?

Comment: Copying a small set to a new table will always be faster than deleting the majority of features from an existing one.

Comment: I have approx 200,000 observations to keep (and 200,000 to delete), is that too large to do a copy with?

Comment: DELETEs take longer than INSERTs; I would export to a new table for anything more than one quarter (or maybe one tenth) of the rows to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [Table Select (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//000800000007000000) tool to select all the records with distance less than 250m out into a new table.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tool Make Query Table and specify your condition in the query.

- For Input Tables specify your table.
- Under Fields choose all of them.
- Use NEAR_DIST <= 250 as an expression.

Output table contains only the rows where the NEAR_DIST is 250 or less.